# DynamicDataDisplay D3 fixed Axis

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I'm using D3 to create several graphics side by side and I would like to have the scale of the axis to be the same and when it changes. I mean, on the following graphics, when I move with the mouse the Y axis of one graphic, I want the over graphics to move as well.

Thanks for your help.

image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1j5D.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you have several graphs and you want them to all move the same, you would be looking for the WidthSpring. There is a great article on it online by Fellice Pollano that you can check out [here](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/05/25/DynamicDataDisplaySynchronizeAxis.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I took a look at that, but in fact the implementation of SynchroVisible has been done by Fellice Pollano and is not by default on the DLL ( even on the last source-code) I had to merge by hand.